# Laravel - Dynamically loading content within a tabbed pane

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

I believe i have the structure of everything correct.
But the tab links (which are correct) within the page do not force the page to refresh?
Changing the URI and altering the Tag parameter will make the page load, so its kind of working?
But the links don't work?
Also, is this the best way of doing this?

**Routes (web.php)**

```
Route::get('/admin/site', [SiteController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('admin.adminSiteDash');

Route::get('/admin/site/{tab?}', [SiteController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('admin.adminSiteDash.Tab');
```

**Site Controller**

```
public function index() {
   return redirect(route('admin.adminSiteDash.Tab', 'tab1'));
}

public function show($tab = null) {

    if (is_null($tab)) { 
      $tab = 'tab1';
    }
  
    return view('admin.adminSiteDash', [
        'regions' => Region::all(),
        'tab' => $tab
    ]);
}
```

**View (named admin.adminSiteDash)**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <a href="tab1" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link @if($tab === 'tab1') active @endif">Tab 1</a>
    <a href="tab2" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link @if($tab === 'tab2') active @endif">Tab 2</a>
    <a href="tab3" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link @if($tab === 'tab3') active @endif">Tab 3</a>
    <a href="tab4" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link @if($tab === 'tab4') active @endif">Tab 4</a>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  @include('admin.site.prop_' . $tab)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove the Jquery part to the Tabs as really they are just elements..

Removing `data-toggle="tab"`from the ahrefs got behaviour i was after!